# Croogo translate route does not match when invoking helper->url from a plugin

Tags: php, routes, cakephp-1.3

I'm using Croogo 1.3.4 with Translate plugin. The url of my nodes look like:
fra/page/my-slug-for-page

When I access the page fra/page/my-slug-for-page , the Html->image method (invoking app_helper->url) is rendering following link: http://www.mysite.com/fra/page/my-slug-for-page

This is perfectly working.

However, when I'm rendering the same themed layout, in a plugin named myplugin, the Html->image method is rendering http://www.mysite.com/myplugin/page/my-slug-for-page/locale:fra

I traced into the Router:url method, and it appears that no route match, especially not this one that match in other cases.

```
Router::connect('/:locale/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('locale' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

Image link is displayed like this:

```
<?php echo $html->image('/img.png',array('url' => array('locale'=>'fra', 'controller'=> 'page', 'action'=>'my-page-slug')));?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was in plugin name that should be specified, even if empty. Croogo it self feed the plugin name with the current plugin name.

```
<?php echo $html->image('/img.png',array('url' => array('locale'=>'fra', 'controller'=> 'page', 'action'=>'my-page-slug', 'plugin'=>'')));?>
```